# How to change my css code to fit the footer to the bottom of the page for any size of monitor?

Tags: css

I am following this tutorial [link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0815.htm) but do not know how to put the footer on the bottom of the page so when the user open the page the footer is on the very bottom of page regardless of size of the monitor.

So that when they change the size of window or use a bigger monitor footer should be at the end of page.

The important part is that I do not have much text in my content section so the scroll bar is expected to be invisible in any size of monitor.(those that are not very tiny)

*Please also note that I have looked at the previous question but could not find a correct answer.
* If you know of any other tutorial I would appreciate your suggestion. (I need float layout)

Layout

```
 container
    {
       header
       content
       { 
         leftnav | rightnav
       }
       footer
    }
```

Css

```
#container
{
width: 90%;
margin: 10px auto;
background-color: #fff;
color: #333;
border: 1px solid gray;
line-height: 130%;
}

#top
{
padding: .5em;
background-color: #ddd;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#top h1
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#leftnav
{
float: left;
width: 160px;
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
}

#content
{
margin-left: 200px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
padding: 1em;
max-width: 36em;
}

#footer
{
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding: .5em;
color: #333;
background-color: #ddd;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

#leftnav p { margin: 0 0 1em 0; }
#content h2 { margin: 0 0 .5em 0; }
```

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

```
#footer{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial the footer is in a `container div`.
If you remove from the container `width:90%` the example will be rendered across the whole width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sticky wrapper jQuery plugin, or use `position: fixed` with `bottom: 5%` and `left: 0` and margin-left values in -ve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer style="background-color: crimson; color:springgreen; font-family: serif; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; position:absolute; width: 99.82%;margin-left: -6px; margin-right: -6px;"><h1>THIS IS MY FOOTER</h1></footer>
```

**Browser:** Google Chrome

**System Screem:** 15.6"

> I have experienced that the appearance of our divs, headers, footers & navs varies from screen to screen and may be browser to browser.